# How to reuse parts of Windows Workflows?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have 2 different WF workflows, which both use an identical piece of logic.

Currently that part is copypasted from one workflow to another.

How can I use a part of a workflow in two different workflows without duplicating it?

Basically, I want to have one "library" workflow, which is used by the 2 "real" workflows.

Comment: Can you be more specific? It's a transparent logic or may you eventually use it as atomic action? 
For example ReadIntFromString and ReadDoubleFromString have the purpose to read a number from a string. So you can embed your generic activity ReadNumber in a wrapper activity CheckIfIsInt or CheckIfDouble to avoid code duplicates. Hope it's clear.

Comment: I have 2 workflows in the workflow designer, which both have an identical part. I want to cut out that part (at the Workflow designer level), put it in some file and then access it from both workflows. I suppose this is a higher abstraction level than your example. It's not about re-using activities, but about re-using a) activities and b) relations between them as specified in the designer.

Comment: What about Activity Extentions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460215.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Just add a new "Activity Library" project to your solution.
- Create an activity in the library that contains the common part.
- Add a reference to the Activity Library project.
- Build all in release.
- Drop the common activity into your workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new type of activity which is able to start a workflow definition.
So you end up with a workflow definition A, workflow definition B. And within this definitions you can place your custom activity which can execute a new workflow definition C.
So A and B points to C.
Workflow definition C can be defined as a child workflow of A and B.

I think this link is a good starting point.
[http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20do%20I%20invoke%20a%20Child%20Workflow%3f&referringTitle=Microsoft.Activities%20Overview](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20do%20I%20invoke%20a%20Child%20Workflow?&referringTitle=Microsoft.Activities%20Overview)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just make a workflow with the common part and use [LoadAndInvokeWorkflow](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LoadAndInvokeWorkflow) activity to execute it in another workflow.